# How to apportion to fill certain null values

Tags: r

Given this dataset where some quarterly entries are null:

```
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(1234)

df <- tibble(
  date = seq(ymd("2000-01-1"), ymd("2020-12-1"), by = "quarter"),
  x = rnorm(84, mean = 6000, sd = 5000)
)

df$x[sample(nrow(df), 20)] <- 0

df
```

For the third quarter entries where x = 0, how can I apportion the value of the next quarter if that value is greater than 0?

Example: if quarter 3 = 0 and quarter 4 = 100, I'd like to have quarter 3 = 50 and quarter 4 = 50, unless quarter 4 <= 0.

Comment: Can you give an example, or define what you mean by apportion?

Comment: Yes, if quarter 3 = 0 and quarter 4 = 100, I'd like to have quarter 3 = 50 and quarter 4 = 50, unless quarter 4 <= 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
    mutate(grp = cumsum(month(date) != 10)) |>
    mutate(x = case_when(month(date) %in% c(7, 10) &
                             first(x) == 0 ~ mean(x),
                         TRUE ~ x),
           .by = grp) |>
    select(-grp)
```

Then e.g.

```
        date        x
1 2004-07-01     0.00
2 2004-10-01 18079.18
```

turns to

```
        date        x
1 2004-07-01 9039.588
2 2004-10-01 9039.588
```

Comment: By apportion I mean the following: if quarter 3 = 0 and quarter 4 = 100, I'd like to have quarter 3 = 50 and quarter 4 = 50, unless quarter 4 <= 0.

Comment: Thanks, good answer,  I think I need to add    ` mutate(x = case_when(month(date) %in% c(7, 10) &
                             first(x) == 0 & last(x) > 0~ mean(x),
                         TRUE ~ x), `  so that the split only happens when the next Q4 value is positive.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(idx = rev(cumsum(rev(x != 0)))) %>%
  mutate(x = case_when(last(x) > 0 ~ last(x) / n(), TRUE ~ x)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-idx)
```

Output (first 15 rows):

```
         date           x
1  2000-01-01   -35.32875
2  2000-04-01  7387.14621
3  2000-07-01 11422.20588
4  2000-10-01 -5728.48851
5  2001-01-01  8145.62344
6  2001-04-01  8530.27946
7  2001-07-01  3126.30020
8  2001-10-01  3266.84072
9  2002-01-01  3177.74000
10 2002-04-01  1549.81085
11 2002-07-01  3614.03650
12 2002-10-01  1008.06778
13 2003-01-01  2118.73053
14 2003-04-01  5398.73515
15 2003-07-01  5398.73515
```